# Registration form rules

Tags: legal

I read somewhere that a registration form has to have some sort of notification about the storing of their info, is this true? If so, where can I find those rules?

Comment: @Lord I requested that it be deleted on meta and the migration cleared here; apparently only the second half happened

Comment: Don't punish me! I dind't re-open it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is in the general case you may be referring to your countries equivalent of the Data Protection Act (which we have in the UK). It depends on the type of information you are holding and your jurisdiction. It generally only applies to details such as medical or financial ones. I don't know of any jurisdiction where email addresses, names and the like must be given the same protections.

If you're working in the Netherlands have a look at [this](http://www.dutchdpa.nl/Pages/home.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[amitywebsolutions.co.uk](http://www.amitywebsolutions.co.uk/blog/legal/259-legal-requirements-for-your-website-privacy-policy-tcs-data-protection-and-more/) has a summary covering "Legal Requirements for Your Website" (UK/EU regulations)

> - Company Information
> - Web Accessibility and the Disability Discrimination Act
> - The Data Protection Act
> - Consumer Protection (Distance Selling) Regulations
> - Electronic Commerce Regulations (EC Directive)
> - PCI DSS
> - The EU Anti Spam Laws

... and for the UK, the [Information Commissioner's Office](http://www.ico.gov.uk/for_organisations/data_protection/topic_guides/online.aspx) have published further guidance.